# Rails insert into db with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

How can i add data in my database with the following model?

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
has_many :user_groups
has_many :groups, through: :user_groups

class Group < ActiveRecord:Base
has_many :user_groups
has_many :users, through: :user_groups

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord:Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :group
```

Now i'm using this code to save the new record

```
#group_controller
def create
  @group = current_user.groups.build(params...)
  if @group.save
  #my redirect etc...
end
```

Well, this will create an row in my group table with the corrects parameters etc but my join table is still empty... why? Can anybody explain these? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are building the group and saving it, but not the relationship.

```
if @group.save
  current_user.groups << @group
```

will fix it.

Comment: Okay... i thought rails will do this for me automaticlly